# Find m so equations have common tangent

Tags: tangent-line

There are given two equations:

> $f$: $y=\ln x$ and $g$: $y=mx^2$

The question is:

> Find values of $m$ so these equations have common tangent.

**Solution**

I found the derivative of $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ so I got

$1/x = 2mx$.

$m = 1/2x^2$

Comment: Solve for `m`...

Comment: Is $f(x)=\ln (x)$? If so, wouldn't $f'(x)=\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: The derivative of $ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$.

Comment: Oh sorry, completely my mistake.I was doing second derivate of lnx for no reason

Comment: Solving the equation on the second last line gives $m=\frac{1}{2x^2}$.

Comment: @Dave it looks like im having a bad day . Thanks for poiting out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A point on the curve $f$ has coordinates $(t,\ln t)$. The tangent line to $f$ at this point has equation
$$
y-\ln t=\frac{1}{t}(x-t)
$$
that can be rewritten
$$
y=\frac{x}{t}-1+\ln t
$$

The tangent line to a point $(u,mu^2)$ to the curve $g$ has equation
$$
y-mu^2=2mu(x-u)
$$
that is
$$
y=2mux-mu^2
$$
The two tangent coincide if and only if the system
$$
\begin{cases}
\dfrac{1}{t}=2mu \\[6px]
-1+\ln t=-mu^2
\end{cases}
$$
has solution (in the unknowns $t$ and $u$).

Comment: Thank you for detailed answer!